# React Native WebView js injection

Tags: react-native, webview

I have a `WebView` component which initially has page 1 and on a button click opens 2nd page. I would like to inject javascript on the 2nd page. the `WebView` prop `injectedjavascript` injects javascript on the 1st page only. How can I inject my js code on the 2nd page?

```
<WebView
  source={{html: htmlCode}}
  style={{flex: 1}}
  javaScriptEnabled
  injectedJavaScript={'document.getElementById("myform").submit();'}
/>
```

1st page
htmlCode :

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id = "myform" action="http:myurl.com" method="post">
        <input id = "myname" value="abc"/>
        <input id = "myroll" value="123"/>
        <input id = "myclass" value="12"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

2nd page
the html in the url "http:myurl.com" :-

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p> Hello world </p>
    <input id="hello" value="bye"> 
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to inject my javascript on the 2nd page.
how can I do it ?

Comment: It will be difficult to help without seeing the code.

Comment: sure. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the answer. Hopefully somebody else will.

Comment: Kindly help if someone knows.